# Printing XML data in a DATA GRID VIEW C#

Tags: c#, xmlnodelist

```
 <Tools ID="RDM">
  <ButtonTool>
    <Item ID="IS" TYPE="IS" NAME="IS" COLUMN_ID="ID" ORDERNO="UID" />
    <Item ID="CS" TYPE="PROC" NAME="ABC">
      <Path>C:\ProgramData\base\VLaunch.exe</Path>
      <Parameter>/USERID=acc /USERPASS=abc /ID=ITEM /QUERY</Parameter>
    </Item>
    <Item ID="APPLICATION" TYPE="PROC" NAME="XYZ">
      <Path>D:\ACT\bin\ACTLancher.exe</Path>
      <Parameter>%U %I -APPLICATION $$PATIENTID$$ CT $$RDM_UID$$</Parameter>
    </Item>
    <Item ID="REPO" TYPE="PROC" NAME="AAA">
      <Path>C:\app\LUC\Launcher.exe</Path>
      <Parameter>/USERID=acc /USERPASS=abc /ID=ITEM</Parameter>
    </Item>
  </ButtonTool>
</Tools>
```

I'm new to this field and facing some issues,
this is a xml file which I want to print in a data grid view, I'm able to print the value of item tag in the grid but not able to print the path and parameter tag in the grid. I tried using SelectingsingleNode but it will always print the first path and parameter in the grid.
the code I used to until now is as follows....any help will be appreciated

```
   XmlNodeList nl = _doc.SelectNodes("Tools/ButtonTool/Item");
                for (int i = 0; i < nl.Count; i++)
                {
                    string sType = base.Com.GetAttri(nl[i], "TYPE", "");
                    if (sType == "RIS")
                    {
                        _dt.Rows.Add(base.Com.GetAttri(nl[i], "ID", ""),
                                  base.Com.GetAttri(nl[i], "TYPE", ""),
                                  base.Com.GetAttri(nl[i], "NAME", ""),
                                  base.Com.GetAttri(nl[i], "COLUMN_ID", ""),
                                  base.Com.GetAttri(nl[i], "ORDERNO", ""));
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        //for (int j = 0; j < nl.Count; j++)
                        //{
                        XmlNodeList pl = _doc.SelectNodes("Tools/ButtonTool/Item/Path");
                        txtPath.Text = pl.ToString();
                        XmlNode ppl = _doc.SelectSingleNode("Tools/ButtonTool/Item/Parameter");
                        txtUser.Text = ppl.InnerText;
                        //string Path = txtPath.Text;
                        _dt.Rows.Add(base.Com.GetAttri(nl[i], "ID", ""),
                              base.Com.GetAttri(nl[i], "TYPE", ""),
                              base.Com.GetAttri(nl[i], "NAME", ""),
                              base.Com.GetAttri(nl[i], "COLUMN_ID", ""),
                              base.Com.GetAttri(nl[i], "ORDERNO", ""), txtUser.Text, txtPath.Text
                              );
                        //}

                    }
```

Comment: Q: What is "base"?  If it's a custom class, can you show it to us?

Comment: I'm new to this but I think it is used to get access to the GetAttri() function which is used to get a attribute of a node from xml

Comment: This sounds to me like something that could be fixed with some xpath. When you are selecting a single node out of a document using a generic name, it will always find the first node in the document. Using xpath you can specify the path directly to the node you want while you are looping. Something like /Item[i] where i is your for loop number.  I would start here if you are new to it https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_intro.asp

Comment: when I'm using item[i] it is throwing an exception.

Comment: but it works if I use numbers instead like item[2] but again when new data entered it will still show the same path and parameter.